How to specify the color in a class in Vue?
src/components/HelloWorld.vue
<template>
  <div class="h-screen flex">
    <div class="w-1/2 bg-gradient-to-r from-green-500 to-blue-900"></div>
    <div class="w-1/2 bg-beige"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld'
}
</script>

<style scoped>
.bg-beige {
  background-color: #f5f5dc; /* Color beige */
}
</style>


src/App.vue
<template>
  <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
  <HelloWorld />
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>

src/main.js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './assets/styles.css';

createApp(App).mount('#app')

src/assets/styles.css
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

This is the project structure (done with vue create command):

Based on the style "from-green-500 to-blue-900", the background should be half gradient half beige, but this is what it looks like:

The logo is logo.png, which is not the problem. What am I missing?

Any errors in the console? Do you see the component in the devtools? Do you have a Github link?

hi @kissu no, it is just a testing project I've just created now. no errors nor anything, the code compiles fine

probably the problem occurs in vue 3 using webpack, the following solution helped me

in tailwind.config.js the content property must be set to vue type

    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    module.exports = {
      content: ["./src/**/*.{html,js,vue}"],
      theme: {
        extend: {},
      },
      plugins: [],
    }


npm dependencies

    npm install -D tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer


create postcss.config.js

    const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
    const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss');
    
    module.exports = {
      plugins: [
        tailwindcss,
        autoprefixer,
      ],
    };


make sure your path and file names are correct

    npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/input.css -o ./src/output.css --watch

